# How to get the URL of selected Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I want to appnd data dynamically in Jquery default tabs
but How I can get the selected tab

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">         </script>
 </head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
</ul>
</div>
<input type='button' id='addTab' value='Add Tab'>
<input type='button' id='appendText' value='Add Text in Tab'>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs({
    tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <p title='close' id='removeTab' style='cursor:pointer;display:inline'>x</p></li>"
    });
 });

$(function() {
var index = 0;
$("#addTab").live('click', function() {
    index++;
    var title = 'Tab.....  ' + index;
    var url = '#fragment-' + index;


    addTab(url, title, index);

});

function addTab(url, title, index) {

    $('#tabs').tabs("add", url, title, [index]);
}
$('#removeTab').live('click', function() {
selected = $('p[id=removeTab]').index(this);
    $('#tabs').tabs("remove", [selected]);
});


 $('#appendText').live('click', function() {
    //fragment-1 is hardcoded I want to get the url of tab by clicking on it...  
    $('#fragment-1').append("Bla Bla!!!");
});


});
```

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k44Wk/2/
​
​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append the text with this code:

```
$(".ui-tabs-panel").not(".ui-tabs-hide").append("Bla Bla!!!");
```

Here is the JSFiddle Link..

http://jsfiddle.net/k44Wk/4/

If you want to add Text in Tab Head:

```
$(".ui-tabs-selected").append("Bla Bla!!!");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the index of selected tab, with...

```
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); // selected tab index integer
```

...and map it with the corresponding HTML element.

Alternatively, you can add/remove your own custom class on selected tab, and select it through that class

```
var url = $('.mySelectedTab').child('a').attr('href');
```

**Edit**: actually jQuery might add their own class on the selected tab. It's just not documented clearly anywhere. Try to inspect the element on your browser to find the class.

Comment: See my answer. I reverse engineered the plug-in to get to this information and had been using that method all along. However, I didn't realize until now that you could just call `$tabs.tabs` and use the API. I'll have to play around with that. +1 for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 2):

When you click on a tab, the class "ui-state-active" is applied to it, while that same class is removed from the previously active tab. Knowing this, you can use this class in your CSS selector when targeting it to add content.

Alternatively, you can also use class "ui-tabs-selected".

**jQuery Tabs HTML:**

```
<!-- Tab1: See "ui-state-active" at the end of the class list -->
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#fragment-1">Tab.....  1</a> <p title="close" id="removeTab" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline">x</p></li>

<!-- Tab2: ui-state-active won't appear here until you click the 2nd tab -->
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#fragment-2">Tab.....  2</a> <p title="close" id="removeTab" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline">x</p></li>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// get selected tab, either #fragment-1, #fragment-2, or #fragment-3
var id = $('#tabs').find('.ui-state-active).find("a").attr("href"); 

// now use that id to get a reference to the selected body
$('div'+id).append("Bla!!");
```

Of course, there may very well be an API for more easier access to this information. However, this is a more low-level approach that may help you understand how jQuery tabs works.

Answer (score 1):

try something like :

```
$('#tabs li').click(function(){
   console.log($(this).children('a').attr('href'));
});
```

just typed not tested

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want to get the url of selected tab or append the text in selected tab's panel.
If you want to get the url from selected tab the thing to look for is jQueryUI tab class named: ui-tabs-selected.
But if you want to append the text to selected tab panel the class to look for is "ui-tab-hide" (or rather not to look for). Below is the code for second option. http://jsfiddle.net/gP3YZ/

```
$('#appendText').live('click', function() {
//iterate through all tab panels.
    $('#tabs .ui-tabs-panel').each(function(index) {
         //check if the tab is not hidden, i.e. disregard all hidden tabs.
         if(!($(this).hasClass('ui-tabs-hide'))){
             //do the dew!
             $(this).append("Bla Bla!!!");
             return;
         }
    });
});
```